# Speed comparison of Feldman's software posits ("universal numbers") vs existing hardware floats?

Tags: floating-point, numbers, benchmarking, posit-number-system, universal-number-format

The proposed posits ("universal numbers") implementation [by Michael Feldman](https://www.nextplatform.com/2019/07/08/new-approach-could-sink-floating-point-computation/) seems quite interesting.

Has anyone performed any benchmarks to compare his implementation (in software) against existing hardware floats speeds?

I am curious as to whether there's any speed advantage at all in implementing this for a programming language to use as a default universal number system vs using existing hardware support. It seems doubtful, but certainly worthy of curiosity.

Comment: Doubtful without HW support.  I assume the long-term goal is CPU hardware support for Posits, like how x86 has added hardware support for float16 and bfloat16 with recent AVX-512 extensions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#BF16).  (Not just conversion to/from float32, which x86 has had for a while.)

Comment: I assume the same @PeterCordes, but I find it an interesting topic and would be curious to see any further details and comparisons (which I've not yet found). It seems a worthwhile exercise for someone experienced in this area either which way one may slice it.

Comment: [Wikipedia has a list of benchmarks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unum_(number_format)#Implementations). They seem all pretty slow.

Comment: Interesting figures for these various implementations @MargaretBloom, thanks for sharing that. I don't see any of them claiming to be Feldman's implementation per se (unless his work is embedded into one of the projects and I don't recognize it) and many don't have any actual figures, but you're right - all of the software based implementations that are actually revealed are quite slow (relatively speaking).

Comment: I don't know who Feldman is, sorry. Your link points to an entry-level journalistic article on Posits, it never mentions an implementation from Feldman (which appears to be an [editor](https://twitter.com/hpc_feldman?lang=en) btw). But note that even the VividSparks implementation, which uses 512 cores, is not very fast (~3 Tpops, a single Intel core is close to that in terms of Tflops) so a software implementation (whatever it is) will be very slow (judging from those figures, about 30-40 times slower).